# Removing dynamic template events in Meteor

Tags: events, meteor

So, we all know that you can add events post-render by calling `Template.templateName.events()` and passing in new events. My question is: How do I remove them? I've found that I'm adding them how I like, but I end up with several of the same event, that all fire, and it's causing all sorts of problems. Is there a specific place that meteor stores the actual events? Where I could clear them out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `Template.templateName.__eventMaps = []` did the trick. I run this before creating a new instance of my template, and therefore only get one set of event handlers. woo!

Answer (score 1):

Template events should not be called several times but used once for static event definitions for this template that every instance of the template will listen to.

The [documentation](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-events) is not very helpful here. However, if you need dynamic template events you are still in good hands using the classic `addEventListener` or jQuery `on` and use `bind` to bind them to the template instance.

Don't forget to remove them when required but at least in `Template#onDestroyed`

Comment: I'm asking how to remove them. Adding them is working just fine